# Why my HttpPost can't receive all response data?

Tags: java, android, apache, http

I'm on Android 1.5, and my code is like this:

```
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
HttpEntity entity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params, HTTP.UTF_8);
httpPost.setEntity(entity);

HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
HttpEntity respEntity = response.getEntity();
String result = EntityUtils.toString(respEntity, DEFAULT_CHARSET);
```

After successfully executed these codes, the result is a stripped string. I've tried using browser to test the url+param, it works fine and got all data.

What's wrong with this code? Is there any parameters I need to specified?

Comment: How stripped is stripped? Does the `DEFAULT_CHARSET` match with the actual charset of the response body?

Comment: Yes, the DEFAULT_CHARSET matched the actual charset. I can get like 2k contents and successfully decoded. But can't get all data.

Comment: Sorry to you all, I found in fact the response has full data. It's because of the android.util.Log has a output length limit. So I thought the data is incomplete.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the [`ResponseHandler` pattern](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/httpcomponents/httpclient/branches/4.0.x/httpclient/src/examples/org/apache/http/examples/client/ClientWithResponseHandler.java) instead and see if that gives you better results.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
HttpResponse response=httpclient.execute(httppost);
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
```